# Can I declare a CURSOR after BEGIN statement of trigger in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I need to create a CURSOR after BEGIN statement in a trigger based on a condition like this:

```
IF :OLD.DWF_STATUS = 'P' AND :NEW.DWF_STATUS = 'C' THEN

    DECLARE CURSOR cur_list IS
        SELECT DISTINCT DR_PRJ_ID, STR_EMAIL, DWFU_US_ID
        FROM DOC_WORKFLOW JOIN DOC_WF_USERS ON DWFU_DWF_ID = DWF_ID
        JOIN DOCUMENT_REF ON DWF_DR_ID = DR_ID AND DR_TYPE = 'P'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ST_REGISTER ON STR_ID = DWFU_STR_ID
        WHERE DWF_ID = :NEW.DWF_ID;

END IF;
```

When I compile, I get this error:

> Error(99,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
>      begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
>      current cursor delete  exists prior

How can I declare cursor after BEGIN statement of trigger in Oracle?

Answer (score 5):

DECLARE is the start of a PL/SQL block. A block comprises an optional DECLARE section followed by a BEGIN section, an optional EXCEPTION section and finally an END.

What you have here is a nested block. Oracle expects you to follow it with a BEGIN and END. Like this:

```
IF :OLD.DWF_STATUS = 'P' AND :NEW.DWF_STATUS = 'C' THEN

    DECLARE CURSOR cur_list IS
        SELECT DISTINCT DR_PRJ_ID, STR_EMAIL, DWFU_US_ID
        FROM DOC_WORKFLOW JOIN DOC_WF_USERS ON DWFU_DWF_ID = DWF_ID
        JOIN DOCUMENT_REF ON DWF_DR_ID = DR_ID AND DR_TYPE = 'P'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ST_REGISTER ON STR_ID = DWFU_STR_ID
        WHERE DWF_ID = :NEW.DWF_ID;

    begin
        -- some code here

    end;

END IF;
```

That is, you must write the code to use the Cursor in the block defined by the DECLARE statement. This is because the PL/SQL scope means that variables cannot be referenced outside the block in which they are declared.

So the question is, why are you declaring this cursor in a nested block? When not just declare it at the top of the trigger body?